# Firebase: First write is slow

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Currently developing a hybrid mobile app using ionic. When the app starts up, and a user writes to the Realtime Database for the first time, it's always delayed by around 10 or more seconds. But any subsequent writes are almost instantaneous (less than 1 second).

My calculation of delay is based on watching the database in the Firebase console.

Is this a known issue, or maybe I am doing something wrong. Please share your views.

**EDIT:**

The write is happening via Firebase Cloud Function.

This is the call to the Firebase Cloud function

```
this.http.post(url+"/favouritesAndNotes", obj, this.httpOptions)
  .subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  },(error)=>{
    console.log(error);
  });
```

This is the actual function

```
 app.post('/favouritesAndNotes', (request, response) => {
  var db = admin.database().ref("users/" + request.body.uid);
  var favourites = request.body.favourites;
  var notes = request.body.notes;
  if(favourites!==undefined){
    db.child("favourites/").set(favourites);
  }
  if(notes!==undefined){
    db.child("notes/").set(notes);
  }
  console.log("Write successfull");
  response.status(200).end();
});
```

Comment: Is your user authenticate when you open the app or only at the same time you do the first call ?

Comment: @ChristopheGudlake The user has already logged in.

Comment: they probably close the dyno and reopen it once activity begin.

Comment: @ChristopheGudlake: the question you linked is about the time it takes to start Cloud Functions, while this question is about the Realtime Database. While both are part of Firebase, they're quite different. For example: Firebase Database instances are not "spun down", and I doubt caching would cause this difference.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen my bad, I should have mentioned the write is happening via cloud function.

Comment: Please update your question to include the [minimal, complete code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first time you interact with the Firebase Database in a client instance, the client/SDK has to do quite some things:

1. If you're using authentication, it needs to check if the token that it has is still valid, and if not refresh it.
2. It needs to find the server that the database is currently hosted on.
3. It needs to establish a web socket connection.

Each of these may take multiple round trips, so even if you're a few hundred ms from the servers, it adds up.

Subsequent operations from the same client don't have to perform these steps, so are going to be much faster.

If you want to see what's actually happening, I recommend checking the Network tab of your browser. For the realtime database specifically, I recommend checking the WS/Web Socket panel of the Network tab, where you can see the actual data frames.

Comment: As a not skilled web developer could see benefits on watching a short video example of how doing it