# Swift Firebase first write incredibly slow

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app in production and am doing some updates. I use an old iPhone 5 for testing, and I've noticed that the write times for initial writes to the Firebase database are incredibly slow. When I say slow, I mean it's taking over a minute to do a single write to a single node (70-80 seconds).

Here is the write request (it's very simple):

```
FB.ref
    .child(FB.members)
    .child(currentUser.firstName)
    .updateChildValues([FB.currentPoints: currentUser.currentPoints])
```

The issue is, this only happens on the first write. Subsequent writes are much faster (a couple of seconds at the most), and usually instant.

**What I've Tried**

I've read the documentation, and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53325602/firebase-first-write-is-slow) post here on SO, but it's not helping me.

I also did tests on the **simulator** and found that the write times for initial write is about 7 seconds. That still seems long to me, but nowhere near as long as the 70-80 seconds on the **physical device**.

Simulator initial write: 7 seconds (slow). Subsequent writes: instant-ish

iPhone 5 initial write: 80 seconds (extremely slow!). Subsequent writes: instant-ish

Any ideas on how to speed up that initial write? It's very problematic. For example, if a user logs in to make a quick change and then closes the app, the write will never happen (tested), or the delay will cause other inaccuracies within the app (also tested). What to do?

Is there a setting I can change on my database? Or a rule to adjust in my database rules? Or some code to include in my app?

[image: Xcode Instruments]

Comment: There is no setting to make the database faster or slower. It all depends on the speed of your client, its connection to the servers, its bandwidth, and the amount of data you retrieve.

Comment: Hmmm... I have fast internet connectivity on my device ~25Mbps. And reading is very fast. In fact, I download a lot of data on initial launch (approx. 1.5s to do so). It's just the writing. And only the initial write, that takes so darn long.

Comment: Okay, so your comment pointed me in the right direction. I went back to my other code and found a large Firebase call that was eating up all the bandwidth on the database. It was so busy running this other code (that I thought was small but wasn't), it didn't have the time to get to my new call for 70-80 seconds.

Comment: I ended up editing the other code to do less work on the database, and now everything is working as expected.

Comment: Good to hear you found the cause of the problem! 